# ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, ddl

> ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'StudentID' in the referenced table 'student'

My Create Table SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `mydb`.`University`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`University` (
      `UniversityID` INT NOT NULL,
      `StudentID` INT NOT NULL,
      `UniversityName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `UniversityAddress` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`UniversityID`),
      INDEX `fk_students` (`StudentID` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `StudentID`
        FOREIGN KEY (`StudentID`)
        REFERENCES `mydb`.`Student` (`StudentID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>   Nothing to fetch

Comment: Please show us also the **create table** for **student**, because mysql is telling in your error message that you don't have an index in the table student on StudentID.

Comment: I doubt the design of this db , student should not be an attribute of university, university should be an attribute of student (via a xref/linking/junction table or if laravel pivot table) As is you have multiple entries for the same university.